# Segmentation fault when writing data to a dynamic array

Tags: c, file, struct, segmentation-fault, records

My assignment is to write a file that displays an unknown number of records entered by the user. Each record has the following fields: First Name, Last Name, Address, City, State, Zip Code, and Phone Number.

I assumed the best way to do this would be to define a struct Record with the fields above, then declare an array of `Record`s that would contain as many records as the user entered. To accomplish this I would use a loop to get the inputs for each field per record, then if the user wanted to continue dynamically allocate an extra space in the `Record` array and continue until the user enters no. I encountered an access violation writing location error at line:

```
scanf("%s", records[i]->fname);
```

What's wrong with my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
struct Record;

struct Record
    {
        char fname[51];
        char lname[51];
        char address[51];
        char city[51];
        char state[51];
        int zipcode;
        int phoneNumber;
    };

int main()
{
    FILE *fileWriter;
    const char filename[] = "data.txt";
    char answer = 'y';
    int size = 1;
    int i = 0;
    struct Record **records;
    records = malloc(sizeof(*records)*(size));

    while(answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y')
    {
        printf("First Name: \n");
        scanf("%s", records[i]->fname);

        printf("Last Name: \n");
        scanf("%s", records[i]->lname);

        printf("Address: \n");
        scanf("%s", records[i]->address);

        printf("City: \n");
        scanf("%s", records[i]->city);

        printf("State: \n");
        scanf("%s", records[i]->state);

        printf("Zipcode: \n");
        scanf("%d", records[i]->zipcode);

        printf("Phone Number: \n");
        scanf("%d", records[i]->phoneNumber);
        //stores all record info

        printf("Are there anymore records? [y/n] ");
        answer = getchar();
        if(answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y')
        {
            size++;
            records[i++];
            printf("\n");
        }
        records = realloc(records,sizeof(*records)*(size));
    }

    //open file
    fileWriter = fopen(filename,"wb");

    if(fileWriter != NULL)
    {
        if(fwrite(records,sizeof(*records),size,fileWriter) != 1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to write to %s\n", filename);
            exit(1);
        }
        fclose(fileWriter);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error opening file.");
    }
}
```

**EDITED VERSION**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct Record
    {
        char fname[51];
        char lname[51];
        char address[51];
        char city[51];
        char state[51];
        int zipcode;
        int phoneNumber;
    };




int main()
{
    FILE *fileWriter;
    const char filename[] = "data.txt";
    char answer = 'y';
    int size = 1;
    int i = 0;
    struct Record *records = NULL;
    struct Record *records_temp;




    while(answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y')
    {
        struct Record *records_temp = realloc(records,(size)*sizeof(*records));

        if(records_temp == NULL)  
        {
            free(records); 

        }
        records = records_temp;
        printf("First Name: \n");
        scanf("%s", records[i].fname);
        printf("Last Name: \n");
        scanf("%s", records[i].lname);

        printf("Address: \n");
        scanf(" %[^\n]", records[i].address);

        printf("City: \n");
        scanf("%s", records[i].city);

        printf("State: \n");
        scanf("%s", records[i].state);

        printf("Zipcode: \n");
        scanf("%d", &records[i].zipcode);

        printf("Phone Number: \n");
        scanf("%d", &records[i].phoneNumber);
        //stores all record info

        printf("Are there anymore records? [y/n] ");
        answer = getchar();
        if(answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y')
        {
            size++;
            records[i++];
            printf("\n");
        }

        //open file

    fileWriter = fopen(filename,"wb");

    if(fileWriter != NULL)
    {
        if(fwrite(records,sizeof(*records),size,fileWriter) != 1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to write to %s\n", filename);
            exit(1);
        }
        fclose(fileWriter);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error opening file.");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Note that the line `records[i++];` increments `i` and does nothing else useful.

Comment: Also note that the `struct Record;` line really isn't necessary.  The only time it might make a difference is if you are defining mutually recursive structures in a function scope rather than at file scope (and this use is at file scope).  As it is, the line says "there is a type `struct Record`", and the next block of code says "there is a type `struct Record` and this is how it is defined".

Comment: `records[i]->fname` means `(*records[i]).fname`, which means `(*(*(records + i))).fname`. What does `records + i` point to? What does `*(records + i)` point to?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, note that the question was *What's wrong with my code?*, and your comments are answers to that question.  Contrast them to immibis' comment.  Please consider deleting your comments and posting an answer.

Comment: @user1717828: My comments will remain comments.  They are both mostly minor issues — the major problem is the mismanaged memory allocation described by [schlezzz15](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1929635/schlezzz15) in his [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30448761/15168).

Comment: @immibis I'm trying to make records an array and dynamically allocate memory to determine the size and continuously increase it

Comment: @Karlioh , Also, you need the `&` before the variable name when scanning a `%d`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler , Could you please provide an example for "_The only time it might make a difference is if you are defining mutually recursive structures in a function scope rather than at file scope (and this use is at file scope)_"?

Comment: @CoolGuy: `struct A{ … }; void f(void) { struct A; struct B { …; struct A *a_ref; … }; struct A { …; struct B *b_ref; … }; … }` — without the `struct A;`, the `a_ref` element would point at a structure of the externally defined type, not the mutually recursive pair of structure types. The error messages could be quite confusing too!

Comment: @CoolGuy I've edited my code implementing several corrections regarding memory and no longer get an access violation, however I do seem to get a strange error after trying to get input for the address on a record.  An address has 2 spaces inbetween strings, but when entered this seems to cause a skip in asking for user input, one per space. For example when I type only the address # no skip occurs, but when I type the address # with the street name and spaces it prints the prompt for the city and state, and zipcode, but only gets the input for zipcode

Comment: @Karlioh , It is because `%s` will not scan a space and will stop scanning when it sees one of them. Use `%[^\n]` instead of `%s` if you want to get a line input.

Comment: @CoolGuy I made that change and now the same thing happens but to the line of text I use "%[^\n]".

Comment: @Karlioh , Try adding a space before `%[^\n]`.

Comment: @CoolGuy Ok so now the program runs error free, but the result file has a bunch of crap written on it, strange characters. And on top of that once the program asks the user if their are more records the program exits.

Comment: @Karlioh , I have no idea about `fwrite`. You can post a new question giving the necessary details. Hopefully, someone will answer it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you get a segfault because you haven't allocated memory for the first entity in your `records`.

So to resolve that you need to

```
records[size-1] = malloc(sizeof(Records));
```

To put it in this way:
You have `records` that is a pointer to a pointer to `Records`.
When you did

```
records = malloc(sizeof(*records)*(size));
```

You actually asked for `size` pointers to `Records`.
But that is not enough, you need to allocate another memory to store the actual `Records` so that is why we have to

```
records[size - 1] = malloc(sizeof(Records));
```

**Note**: if `size` > 1 then you should do:

```
int i = 0;
for(;i < size; i++) {
    records[i] = malloc(sizeof(Records));
}
```

In addition to that, why did you go with `Records **`, as [Arjun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997813/arjun-sreedharan) has already explained, you should use `Records *` and fix the part of `realloc`-ing new memory, because if `realloc` fails, it returns `NULL` and you end up with memory leak or another segfault in the worst scenario, either way -- it is not good for your program.

Please see [Arjun's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30449769/1929635)

Answer (score 2):

When you want to dynamically allocate space for a list of `Record`s, you should be doing:

```
struct Record *records;
records = malloc(size * sizeof(*records));
```

This allocates space for `size` number of `Record`s.

To increment the allocated size, you should:

```
struct Record *records_temp = realloc(records, newsize * sizeof(*records));

if (records_temp == NULL) {
    free(records);
    /* die with error -ENOMEM */
}

records = records_temp;
```

Do not `realloc` to the same pointer. It can cause you to leak memory on failure.

**Or**, you can avoid `malloc()` and use just `realloc()` in a loop by providing it with a `NULL` pointer initially.

C 89 standards says:

> 4.10.3.4 The realloc function
>
> If ptr is a null pointer, the realloc function behaves like the malloc
>   function for the specified size.

```
struct Record *records = NULL;
struct Record *records_temp;
size = INITIAL_SIZE;

while (/* your condition */) {
    records_temp = realloc(records, size * sizeof(*records));

    if (records_temp == NULL) {
        free(records);
        /* die with error -ENOMEM */
    }

    records = records_temp;

    /* do stuff */

    size += SIZE_INCREMENT;
}
```

Comment: nicely written! got my upvote + added you to my post!

Answer (score 1):

As [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30448605/segmentation-fault-when-writing-data-to-a-dynamic-array?noredirect=1#comment48979890_30448605), but [declined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30448605/segmentation-fault-when-writing-data-to-a-dynamic-array?noredirect=1#comment48980794_30448605) to make an answer out of his comments:

> Note that the line `records[i++];` increments `i` and does nothing else useful.

And [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30448605/segmentation-fault-when-writing-data-to-a-dynamic-array?noredirect=1#comment48979988_30448605):

> Also note that the `struct Record;` line really isn't necessary. The only time it might make a difference is if you are defining mutually recursive structures in a function scope rather than at file scope (and this use is at file scope). As it is, the line says "there is a type `struct Record`", and the next block of code says "there is a type `struct Record` and this is how it is defined".

When [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30448605/segmentation-fault-when-writing-data-to-a-dynamic-array?noredirect=1#comment48988993_30448605) by [Cool Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3049655/cool-guy) to illustrate what was meant by that, Jonathan [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30448605/segmentation-fault-when-writing-data-to-a-dynamic-array?noredirect=1#comment48990480_30448605):

> ```
> struct A { … };
> struct B { … };
> void f(void)
> {
>     struct A;
>     struct B
>     {
>          …;
>         struct A *a_ref;
>         …
>     };
>     struct A
>     {
>         …;
>         struct B *b_ref;
>         …
>     };
>     …
> }
> ```
>
> Without the `struct A;` line, the `a_ref` element would point at a structure of the externally defined type `struct A`, not the mutually recursive pair of structure types. The error messages could be quite confusing too!  However, reusing type names like this is a bad idea.